# NPM package post install target root directory

Tags: node.js, npm

I have an NPM package that has a post install script such as

```
 "postinstall": "node install.js"
```

I'm trying to target the directory from which the `npm install mypackage` was run originally. Right now I'm resorting to using in install.js some relative path such as

```
 path.normalize(__dirname+'./../../../www');
```

My structure goes as follow

```
 node_modules/@namespace/mypackage
 www
```

But it's kind of ugly and cannot guarantee that this wouldn't break in future revisions of Node/NPM. **Is there a constant** that targets the path from which the `npm install mypackage` was run?
Long story short, I'm moving files into www.